# Verifying a proof of a combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

today I attempted this problem and have a proof I am not sure is correct.

> Show that given any 52 integers, there exist two of them whose sum, or else whose difference is divisible by 100

Firstly it is evident that if the given integers have 2 or more integers that are equal to each other then we are done $\because$
$$
n - n=0\\
\mod(0,100) = 0
$$

Notice that
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\mod(n,100) = \{0\dots99\}$$

Now I use the pigeonhole principle to realise that $$ \lceil 99/52 \rceil = 2$$

Therefore there must be two numbers congurent to each other and we are done.

Comment: If there are only 52 numbers, none of them have to be congruent to any other. Take, for instance, 1, 2, ..., 52. In fact, we have to have 101 numbers before two of them most be congruent. You have to take into account that we're asking for either a sum or a difference, not just a difference.

Comment: Clearly if you take the numbers 1,...,52 then none two are congruent to each other. You used the pigeonhole principle the wrong way around. It is more complicated because in such cases (all remainders different) you should argue about the sum

Answer (score 2):

Moderately alternative description of the answer.

The congruency classes $\pmod{100}$ can be expressed as

$S = \{-49, -48, \cdots, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, \cdots, 49, 50\}$.

Now consider the set $T$ of the absolute value of the *actual* elements in the set $S$:

$T = \{|-49|, |-48|, \cdots, |-1|, |0|, |1|, |2|, |3|, |49|, |50|\}.$

In fact, the set $T$ only has $(51)$ distinct elements.

Per the constraints of the problem, with both $(x + y)$ and $(x - y)$ being interrogated $\pmod{100}$, if any two elements $x,y$ are both represented by the same element in $T$, then you will have that [$\pmod{100}$]:

- either $x \equiv y \implies (x - y) \equiv 0$
- or $x \equiv -y \implies (x + y) \equiv 0$.

Since $T$ has only $51$ distinct elements, in any group of $52$ integers, there must be $2$ of those integers that are represented by the same element in $T$.

Comment: I don't understand how you made the congurency class in this problem

Comment: @SanjayAdhith I created the set $T$ to contain $51$ elements, $49$ of which represented a **pair** of congruency classes.  Thus, one element each was devoted to the congruency classes of $(0)$ and $(50)$. Then, the congruency classes of $(-1)$ and $(+1)$ were combined into the $(+1)$ element in $T$.  Similarly, the congruency classes of $(-2)$ and $(+2)$ were combined into the $(+2)$ element in $T$.  Further, for $k \in \{3,4, 5,\cdots, 49\}$, the congruency class of $(-k)$ and $(+k)$ were combined into the $(+k)$ element in $T$. ...see next comment.

Comment: @SanjayAdhith The idea is as follows.  Suppose that $x,y$ are any two integers that are each mapped to the same element in $T$.  Then one of two things **has** to be true: **Either** $~~[1]~~ x \equiv y\pmod{100}$, in which case $(x - y) \equiv 0 \pmod{100}~~$ **or** $~~[2]~~ x \equiv (-y) \pmod{100}$ in which case $(x + y) \equiv 0 \pmod{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the integers modulo 100 . Then Any integer $x$ of them must has $x \mod 100 \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,99\} $. If there are two integers $x,y$ such that  $x = y \mod 100$ , then their difference $x-y = 0 \mod 100 $. Hence we are done.

Now let's assume the $52$ integers are all different under modulo 100. We want to determine if there are two integers such that their sum is $0$ under modulo $100$. There are 50 situations such that $x+y = 0 \mod 100$ , i.e. $(x,y)\in \{(1,99),(2,98),(3,97),\cdots,(49,51),(50,50) \}$ all in modulo 100. Since we assume all integers are different . $(50,50)$ is not allowed. Now we have 49 pairs $\{(1,99),(2,98),(3,97),\cdots,(49,51) \}$. And we have $52$ integers . So by the pigeonhole principle . There should be $2$ integers fall in a same pair. And their sum is $0$ under modulo $100$.

=========
**Edit:** The entir pairs to make sum is $0$ under modulo $100$ should be $\{(0,0),(1,99),(2,98),(3,97),\cdots,(49,51),(50,50)\}$. The $52$ integers must have 2 integers fall in the same pair. And their sum is $0$ under modulo $100$.

Comment: Maybe I should let pair $(50,50)$ left... I'll see how to fix it .

Comment: You also have to consider the $51$ classes $\{0\}, \{50\}, \{1, 99\}, \{2, 98\}, \ldots, \{49, 51\}$.  Since there are $52$ different numbers, two of them must be in the same class, which allows you to reach the desired conclusion.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes , should count 0, 50 too.